# How do I remove nodes from a Clang AST?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I have an AST in Clang, which has been generated by a `CompilerInstance`. I would like to prune all nodes that match a certain predicate.

What I am not sure about is how this is supposed to be done. I have a few specific, and related, questions:

- Are Clang nodes mutable?
- Is it recommended to modify nodes during an walk by a visitor?
- Should I call `delete` on a nodes that I remove, or does Clang have internal memory management?
- Are there any concurrency issues that I should be aware of?
- Can I delete the corresponding LLVM code at the same time?

Comment: What kind of predicate? How do you want to prune the nodes? (You can't just remove one argument to a binary operator, for example.) IMO this question is too broad, and it doesn't include any of the code you've used.

Comment: What do you mean "prune"?   If I have  A->B->C, and I prune B, I get ... what? A tree with a hole in it?  I don't think you can "prune".  You might be able to replace:   A->NOP->C.   Why don't you provide some examples?

Comment: @jtbandes A predicate would just be a function that takes a Decl and returns a bool. It could test the name, for example.

Comment: @IraBaxter An example of something to remove would be a global function `extern int foo() { return 17; }`

Comment: So if Clang represents global declarations in an AST as   decllist(decl1,declist(decl2,declist(decl3,...)) I think you want remove decl2 producing declist(decl1,declist(decl3,...))  ...?

Comment: I am not aware of all of the details of how Clang represents global declarations (I am still learning the library), but that sounds correct.

Comment: The Clang AST is a representation of the source code. If you want to remove a global function in a file, it is possible to use the source manager to get the string location, and you can remove the string or replace with another string.

Comment: You can create your own AST node using Create method (for example RecordDecl has method Create). Please have a look at the similar problem here stackoverflow.com/questions/41550891/adding-nodes-to-clangs-ast